# Storing credit cards in memory (PCI Compliance)

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, credit-card, pci-compliance

So, lets say I have a single page application where a user may purchase multiple products back to back (lets say they're game coins). I select a product, the app prompts me for my credit card, I enter it, and then I need to purchase another product.

When a user enters their credit card information, the app puts that information in an object store to later populate into a payload to send over to an API. The card is stored in memory only, not in a cookie, or localStorage, or server session.

EG:

```
var card = $('form[name=creditcard]').serializeObject();
app.purchase({ product_id: 9, payment: { amount: 5,  card: card }})
```

When the user refreshes their browser, the card variable no longer exists, so it cannot be accessed or restored at that point. If the user were to purchase another product, would it be against PCI compliance to use those same values during the browser session versus prompting them for their credit card again?

Comment: i don't understand why you just don't perform checkout after the cart has been completed. So add items to the cart and ask for the card only when user press a "buy" button that triggers the credit card form to show and perform the checkout

Comment: @LelioFaieta Because the user purchases a product that expires over time, then purchases again.